# Using threads to speedup deploying

Tags: multithreading, plugins, deployment, artifactory

I am trying to use threads inside my own plugin. I need to deploy 5 files into Artifactory simultaneously to save time.

```
    baseDir.eachFile {
      def Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
          def InputStream fileAsInputStream = new File (it.getAbsolutePath()).newInputStream()
          def File fileRepoPath = new File (baseDirInRepo, it.getName())

          if(!deployRepoMetadata(item.repoPath.repoKey, fileRepoPath, fileAsInputStream)) {
            throw new Exception ("Can't deploy " + fileRepoPath + " for package " + item.name)
          }
        }
      }
      thread.start()
    }
def boolean deployRepoMetadata(String repoKey, File deployPath, InputStream binary) {

    def String targetRepoKey = repoKey
    def String targetPath = deployPath

    def RepoPath deployRepoPath = RepoPathFactory.create(targetRepoKey, targetPath)
    repositories.deploy(deployRepoPath, binary)
}
```

But I've got the following error:

```
User _system_ is not permitted to deploy
```

How can I deal with this error?

Comment: what type of plugin is it?

Comment: It is storage plugin

Comment: And I have another one question. Is it possible to make deploy inside the plugin as SYNC operation?

Comment: Are you using the asSystem closure? your question is missing the code which performs the deployment

Comment: I am not using asSystem closure. I tried but with the same error.

Comment: The most strange thing that deployed files owner is _system_, but if I am trying to use threads the error is about _system_ has no permissions for that.

Comment: I think the issue is with opening the thread from the plugin. I suspect you lose the context in which the plugin is running

Comment: Is that my programming mistake or what?

Comment: Is it possible to differ repository deleting and package deleting?